# Will metropolis delay the difficulty bomb?

Tags: hardforks, difficulty-bomb, metropolis

Vitalik [said](https://github.com/ethereum/pm/blob/master/All%20Core%20Devs%20Meetings/Meeting%2014.md#1-eip-186-reduce-eth-issuance-before-proof-of-stake-core-devs) the "ice age will be delayed anyways" (with metropolis).

> It's not that important or applicable either way, though on the other hand that given network going to be mucking around with mining rewards anyway because we will be delaying the ice age. I don't see any extreme case in either direction, I guess.

Maybe I'm blind: But I can't seem to find any details about the new mechanics of the difficulty bomb, any adjustments or even a total removal? **Where is this specified?** Could anyone guide me? Will metropolis delay the difficulty bomb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see "eip-649: Metropolis Difficulty Bomb Delay"

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/669

Comment: Yes, and I'm the author of that EIP. Thanks anyways :p

Answer (score 0):

Pure speculation but slowing down the ice age with the metropolis release and using PoS in dual mode to PoW (which I think I heard will be the case in the transition phase) would give miners an incentive to switch to metropolis instead of causing a hard permanent fork by not updating (and opposing PoS).

Comment: On a second thought: PoS isn't planned for metropolis I guess so my point may be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because if not stopped or delayed the Ethereum block-chain will be un-usable by end of year.

So definitely Yes (or >10min blocks)